pyelftools "Magic number does not match" but the ELF magic number is correct
So I have this function that attempts to return the length of an ELF. My use for this is extracting ELF's from a memory dump.
from elftools.elf.elffile import ELFFile

def get_elf_size(start_loc, file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        f.seek(start_loc)
        magic_number = f.read(4)
        if magic_number != b'\x7fELF':
            raise ValueError(f"No ELF header found at offset {start_loc} in {file_path}")
        
        f.seek(start_loc)
        elf = ELFFile(f)
        max_offset = 0
        
        for segment in elf.iter_segments():
            segment_end = segment['p_offset'] + segment['p_filesz']
            if segment_end > max_offset:
                max_offset = segment_end

        return max_offset

However, I keep getting this error
...
File "/home/repos/math/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/elftools/elf/elffile.py", line 570, in _identify_file
    elf_assert(magic == b'\x7fELF', 'Magic number does not match')
  File "/home/repos/math/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/elftools/common/utils.py", line 80, in elf_assert
    _assert_with_exception(cond, msg, ELFError)
  File "/home/repos/math/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/elftools/common/utils.py", line 143, in _assert_with_exception
    raise exception_type(msg)
elftools.common.exceptions.ELFError: Magic number does not match

pyelftools clearly checks the magic number and says it does not match the ELF magic number, but my ValueError is not ever raised in the function and when I print the magic number that I read with magic_number = f.read(4), it says the magic number is '\x7fELF'. The start_loc is a value generated from binwalk and is accurate because I check the magic number. It's just that pyelftools that doesn't like it.
So my question is, why is it when I check the magic number myself it looks and my ValueError is not raised, but pyelftools throws an error that the magic number is not correct?

When you call f.seek(start_loc), you're moving the file pointer to start_loc. You then read the magic number correctly, but right after that, you seek to start_loc again, which is unnecessary because you're already at that position.
def get_elf_size(start_loc, file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        f.seek(start_loc)
        magic_number = f.read(4)
        if magic_number != b'\x7fELF':
            raise ValueError(f"No ELF header found at offset {start_loc} in {file_path}")

        # No need to seek again
        # f.seek(start_loc)
        # Instead of seeking again, just create ELFFile from current position
        elf = ELFFile(f)



This still gives me the same error, although I think I found the issue, this line of code https://github.com/eliben/pyelftools/blob/main/elftools/elf/elffile.py#L81 seeks to the beginning of the file, in my case, the start of the memory dump, and checks the magic number from there. The start of the memory dump is not the ELF magic number. Thanks for the advice though I didn't think about that.

Or this line, https://github.com/eliben/pyelftools/blob/main/elftools/elf/elffile.py#L591.

This answer is wrong: reading 4 bytes advances the file position, so you are in fact not at the position where the ELF begins.
